# Auto enable free shipping for Cash on delivery payment method in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, payment-method

How do I Remove Shipping Charges from Cart when Cash on Delivery *(COD)* is selected and Add Shipping Charges to Cart if `Stripe` *(Credit Card)* is selected in woocommerce?

For Example, shipping to Canada costs `$4`.

If Cash on delivery *(COD)* is selected in payment options, I want to offer "free shipping" and remove shipping section from the cart but if credit cart payment option is selected in payment gateway by the buyer I want to add those shipping charges based on shipping rates set in shipping classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very simple way:

- Go in WooCommerce Settings > Checkout > Cash on delivery.
- Add **`Free Shipping`** in **"Enable for shipping methods"** option field:

[image]

> Now **Free shipping** will be enabled when **Cash on delivery** is selected.